# Use of uninitialized value within XXXX in concatenation (.) or string at image_magick.pl line XX

Tags: perl, compare, undefined, perlmagick

I wrote a program to compare the image files of two folders(having 1000 files each) with some logic [(see this SO question)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13741033/how-can-i-compare-more-number-of-images-in-two-folders-using-perl).

While executing it is comparing successfully until 900 images but then it gives an error like `Use of uninitialized value within @tfiles2 in concatenation (.) or string at  C:\dropbox\Image_Compare\image_magick.pl line 55` (#3).
And then I get a popup error like `Perl Command Line Interpreter has stopped working`, so I close the program.

My code is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
 use Image::Magick;
 no warnings 'uninitialized';
 use warnings;
 use diagnostics;
#use strict;
 use List::Util qw(first);

    my $directory1="C:/dropbox/Image_Compare/folder1";
    opendir(DIR, $directory1) or die "couldn't open $directory1: $!\n";
    my @files1 = grep { (!/^\./) && -f "$directory1/$_" } readdir(DIR);
    closedir DIR;
    print @files1;
    print 'end of files1';
    my $directory2="C:/dropbox/Image_Compare/folder2";
    opendir(DIR, $directory2) or die "couldn't open $directory2: $!\n";
    my @files2= grep { (!/^\./) && -f "$directory2/$_" } readdir(DIR);
    closedir DIR;
    print @files2;
    print 'end of files2';
    print $files1[0];
    foreach my $fils2 (@files2)
    {
        $g1 = Image::Magick->new;
        $g2 = Image::Magick->new;
        $temp1 = $g1->Read( filename=>"C:/dropbox/Image_Compare/folder1/".$files1[0].""); 
        $temp1 = $g2->Read( filename=>"C:/dropbox/Image_Compare/folder2/".$fils2."");
        $g3 = $g1->Compare( image=>$g2, metric=>'AE' ); # compare
        $error1 = $g3->Get( 'error' );
        #print $error1;
        if ($error1 == '0') 
        {
            print "Matching image is:"; 
            print $fils2 . "\n"; 
            my $tdirectory2="C:/dropbox/Image_Compare/folder2";
            opendir(DIR, $tdirectory2) or die "couldn't open $directory2: $!\n";
            my @tfiles2 = grep { (!/^\./) && -f "$tdirectory2/$_" } readdir(DIR);
            closedir DIR;
            #my $index = firstidx { $_ eq'"' .$fils2.'"' } @tfiles2;
            my $index = first { $tfiles2[$_] eq $fils2} 0..$#tfiles2;
            #print $fils2;
            print $index;
            my $i=0;
            foreach my $fils1 (@files1)
            {
                print 'ganesh';
                print $files1[$i];
                print $tfiles2[$index];
                print 'gowtham'; print "<br />";
                #print @tfiles2;
                $g4 = Image::Magick->new;
                $g5 = Image::Magick->new;
                $temp2 = $g4->Read( filename=>"C:/dropbox/Image_Compare/folder1/".$files1[$i].""); 
                $temp2 = $g5->Read( filename=>"C:/dropbox/Image_Compare/folder2/".$tfiles2[$index]."");
                $g6 = $g4->Compare( image=>$g5, metric=>'AE' ); # compare
                $error2 = $g6->Get( 'error' );
                $i++;
                $index++;
                if ($error2 == '0') {}
                else {print "Image not matching:"; print $tfiles2[$index]; last;}
                #if ($i == '800') {last;}


            }
            last
        }
    }
```

Can anyone please help, where i am doing a mistake.

Folder 1 file names: 0025.bmp to 1051.bmp;

Folder 2 file names: 0000.bmp to 1008.bmp;

Thanks
Ganesh

Comment: first impression: use Carp::Always, it may help for help:)

Comment: you might have a corrupt image file? Have you tried with a different set of images? Does it always stop at exactly the same place?

Comment: This code could use some refactoring; seperating the code into easily testable subroutines would improve readability and testability, while reducing the chance of simple typos. (Loading two images and comparing them, then getting the error is a common operation; as is loading a directory.) Also, turn `strict` back on.

Comment: Why are you adding `.""` in this expression: `"C:/dropbox/Image_Compare/folder2/".$fils2.""`  It makes no sense to add an empty string to the end of the string you've built.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know which the offending line is, but one of these is likely to be the candidate:

```
$temp2 = $g5->Read( filename=>"C:/dropbox/Image_Compare/folder2/".$tfiles2[$index]."");
```

or

```
else {print "Image not matching:"; print $tfiles2[$index]; last;}
```

Do note that you increment `$index` whether or not it is inside the array bounds. You do not check for the condition `$index > $#tfiles`, which should break the loop.

You might want to assert that both input arrays contain >> 900 elements, by printing the length like `print "length: ", scalar @array, "\n";`.

You can test at which index the `undefined` error actually happens by testing for definedness of the elements in the arrays:

```
if (not defined $tfiles[$index] or not defined $files1[$i]) {
   die "There was an undefined element at index=$index, i=$i";
}
```

But then again, the offset between `$i`, and `$index` is constant (as mentioned in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13741593/1521179)), so you don't have to actually carry two variables.

A simple comparator subroutine could make your code more readable, thus aiding debugging (see [procedural programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procedural_programming)).

```
# return true if matching, false otherwise.
sub compare_images {
   my ($file1, $file2) = @_;
   my $image1 = Image::Magick->new;
   $image1->Read(filename => $file1);
   my $image2 = Image::Magick->new;
   $image2->Read(filename => $file2);
   my $result = $image1->Compare(image => $image2, metric => 'AE')->Get('error');
   # free memory
   undef $image1;
   undef $image2;
   return 0 == $result;
}
```

called like

```
my $image_root = "C:/dropbox/Image_Compare";
my ($folder1, $folder2) = qw(folder1 folder2);
unless (compare_images("$image_root/$folder1/$files1[$i]", 
                       "$image_root/$folder2/$tfiles[$index]")) {
   print "Images not matching at index=$index, i=$i\n";
   print "filename: $tfiles[$index]\n";
   last;
}
```

You could read your directories like

```
sub get_images_from_dir {
   my ($dirname) = @_;
   -d $dirname or die qq(The path "$dirname" doesn't point to a directory!);
   opendir my $dir => $dirname or die qq(Can't open "$dirname": $!);
   my @files = grep {!/^\./ and -f "$dirname/$_"} readdir $dir;
   closedir $dir;
   unless (@files) { die qq(There were no interesting files in "$dirname".) }
   return @files;
}
```

Steps like these make code more readable and make it easy to insert checks.

Comment: Until now i was stuggling with this error and somehow finally able to getrid of it. It is not a solution but instead i have used another method to compare. Thank you all for your support